# Multiple checkbox filter using form with pagination in laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination

I am using form with post method and there are multiple checkbox, when i check a checkbox and submit form, it work properly and result come with pagination, but when i click next link of pagination it shows an error of 404 page not found.

View : -

```
<form action="{{ route('trainer.filter') }}" method="post">
        @csrf
          <!-- Name -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Search" name="keywords" aria-label="Search">
          <h6 class="black-text mt-2 "><b class="category">Areas of Experties</b></h6>
          <!-- Copy -->
          @foreach ($expertise_areas as $expertise_area)
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-1" style="padding-left: 3px;">
              <label for="expertise_area">
                <input type="checkbox" name="expertise_area[]" value="{{ $expertise_area->id }}">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $expertise_area->name }}
              </label>
            </div>
          @endforeach

          <!-- State -->
          <h6 class="black-text mt-2 "><b class="category">Trainer Location (STATE)</b></h6>
          <select class="form-default browser-default custom-select mb-4" name="state" id="state">
             <option selected disabled>Choose State</option>
             @foreach ($states as $state)
             <option value="{{ $state->id }}">{{ $state->name }}</option>
             @endforeach
          </select>
          <h6 class="black-text mt-2 "><b class="category">Trainer Location (City)</b></h6>
          <!-- City -->
          <select class="browser-default custom-select mb-4" name="city" id="city">
             <option selected disabled>Choose City</option>
             @foreach ($cities as $city)
             <option value="{{ $city->id }}">{{ $city->name }}</option>
             @endforeach
          </select>
          <!-- Send button -->
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit">Search</button>
       </form>
```

Pagination link : -

```
{{ $trainers->links() }}
```

Route : -

```
Route::post('trainer/filter', 'HomeController@trainerFilter')->name('trainer.filter');
```

Controller : -

```
public function trainerFilter(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->has('keywords')) {
        $trainers = Trainer::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->keywords.'%')
                    ->orWhere('state_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->keywords.'%')
                    ->orWhere('city_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->keywords.'%')->orderBy('ranking', 'asc')->paginate(5);
    }}
```

Comment: The controller code does not seem a minimal example, please can you add some more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed to *persist the parameters* you use in the *where* inside the **controller** through the different pages of the *resultset*.

Looking at the controller code you posted you can try to append the `keywords` parameter to the *pagination links*, something like that:

```
{{ $trainers->appends(['keywords' => $keywords])->links() }}
```

And remember to pass `['keywords' => $request->keywords]` to the view.

Comment: i am not sending keywords, i am only sending expertise_area named checkbox when i check a checkbox, there are multiple search like input type text and checkbox and select box

Comment: Watching at your controller code you are using only the `keywords` parameter to filter `$trainers`, My answer is based on the code you posted and I think I gave you more than an hint to solve your pagination problem.

Comment: ok bro, i got it. actually i am sending more search items. like text box named keywords, checkbox named expertise_area and select box named state and city.

Comment: @krish-bhardwaj Just appends more parameters like I show in the answer. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helps you.